# Can we create the Custom Cell with the UIPickerView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have to create the custom TableView with the picker control in multiple rows,can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the *UIPickerView* as a *subView* of *UITableViewCell*.

```
[cell.contentView addSubView:pickerView];
```

Don't forget to return the appropriate height from *heightForRowAtIndexPath:* method.

```
if (cellContainsPickerView) return 200.0; // The height of the picker view
```